# Android Java Notification

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

This code isn't working for me it should make notification every 2 sec the app runs with no errors and then after 2 sec keeps giving me messages you're app has stopped working.
I added these codes:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <service android:name="NotificationService" android:exported="false"/>
            <receiver android:name="BootReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.company.app"/>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
startActivity(new Intent(this,NotificationService.class));
```

**NotificationService.java**

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mTimer=new Timer();
        mTimer.schedule(timerTask,2000,2*1000);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    private Timer mTimer;
    TimerTask timerTask=new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e("log","Running");
            notifiy();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            mTimer.cancel();
            timerTask.cancel();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent intent=new Intent("com.company.app");
        intent.putExtra("your value","torestore");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
    public void notifiy(){
        IntentFilter intentFilter=new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("RSSPullService");

        Intent mIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(""));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),0,mIntent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Context context=getApplicationContext();

        Notification.Builder builder=new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("T")
                .setContentText("M")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                ;//.setSmallIcon();

        Notification notification=builder.build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1,notification);

    }
}
```

**BootReceiver.java**

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Service stops","ohhhhhhh");
        context.startService(new Intent(context,NotificationService.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! *"We want"* you to try to write some code to attempt to solve your problem before asking here. For more info, here is a complimentary [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You may [edit] your question to make sure you follow that.

Comment: ok  working on that

Comment: Also feel free to check the [help center section on asking quality questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)